# Websocket php server

Tags: php, javascript, websocket

Дайте, пожалуйста, пример создания сервера вебсокет на php, сервер должен лишь слушать что ему посылают и отправлять это же в ответе.

Облазил кучу сайтов, прочитал кучу инфы, клиент на JS, там ничего сложного.

Вот так идет попытка соединения

```
this.socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + location.hostname + ':8090'  + '/' + this.opt.update.handler );
```

получаю ошибку в браузере:

> WebSocket connection to
>   'ws://test-zadacha.loc:8090/handler-socket.php' failed: Error in
>   connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

сервер брал [отсюда](https://github.com/hharek/zn_websocket/blob/master/zn_websocket.php)

Comment: Вы точно указали правильный порт?

Comment: @Darth да вроде да, и там и там 8090

Comment: @Darth иногда соединение происходит, но в большей части сервер пишет, что отсутствуют необходимые заголовки

Comment: Ваша проблема [решена](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706832/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-websocket?noredirect=1#comment1053331_706832). Сам мучался неделю