# Подключение по websocket

Tags: php, javascript, nginx, websocket

Не могу подключиться по вебсокету на свой сервер на собственный порт http://localhost:1100
после 10 секундного ожидания выдает ошибку в консоли браузера

```
'wss://tel.buy-tires.ru:1100/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

код javascript

```
<script>
            var socket= new WebSocket('ws://tel.buy-tires.ru:1100/');
            socket.onopen = function() {
              console.log("Соединение установлено.");
            };
        </script>
```

на сервере стоит сокет сервер на порту 1100. 
если прослушать все порты командой sudo lsof -i то выдает

```
TCP localhost:1100 (LISTEN)
```

пробовал настраивать nginx

```
location /ws/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1100;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

}
```

сокет клиенты, запущенные на этом сервере отлично общаются с сокет сервером на  ip localhost порту 1100

я попросил админа открыть порт 1100 на pfsense - открыли.

в командной строке windows запущенной от администратора через telnet прослушивал порт 80 - соединение устанавливается, а вот на 1100 залезть не может. Я впервые сталкиваюсь с настройками такого рода, прочитал много статей - собственно все действия которые я проделал от туда взяты. Как дальше быть не знаю.

17,08,2017

Благодаря @D-side понял почему не мог прослушивать входящие извне соединения, потому что обращался не потому адресу, а мне в соответствии с настройками nginx надо было обращаться к

```
 var socket= new WebSocket('ws://tel.buy-tires.ru/ws/');
```

теперь сервер видит что идет подключение к сокету, но почему то браузерный websocket не видит сообщения, которое я закладываю в буфер сокета - ответа от сервера в виде http заголовка - после долгого ожидания к нему приходит заголовок сформированный nginx код 502, хотя я ему отсылаю 101

также мне не нужны подмененные nginx ом подмененные ВХОДЯЩИЕ заголовки, поэтому упростил настройки до

```
location /ws/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:1100;
}
```

причем когда вырубаю сокет сервер, вебсокет, ждущий ответа - тут же реагирует что соединение разорвано

Comment: Сокет-сервер или вебсокет-сервер? Это совершенно разные вещи

Comment: Если у вас сокет-сервер слушает только локальную петлю, снаружи вы туда никак не попадёте без помощи от самого сервера. А проксирование вебсокетов на nginx так не делается.

Comment: Насколько я понял @andreymal из примеров в интернете  
Сокет-сервер или вебсокет-сервер отличаются содержанием буфера сокета при рукопожатии.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста @D-side какую "петлю" должен прослушивать сокет сервер, чтобы socket_bind до прослушки Привязывает нужное имя к сокету. В настоящий момент мне нужно получить изменение в главном сокете (в socket_select) чтобы я смог выполнить socket_accept, т.е. зафиксировать - что на сервер постучались. На этой базе я уже смогу наладить общение сокет сервера с вебсокетом. По другому спрошу - какую помощь должен оказать сервер что бы слушать запросы извне?

Comment: Локальная петля, она же loopback, это такой программный сетевой адаптер, способный слать пакеты только в пределах машины, на которой находится. Если вы слушаете адрес `127.0.0.1`, то вы слушаете loopback Нужно прослушивать реальный сетевой адаптер.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста @D-side - какую информацию нужно копать чтобы обучить сокет сервер слушать реальный сетевой адаптер. Спасибо за вашу помощь

Comment: Последние два предложения моего прошлого комментария (в предпоследнем я почему-то забыл поставить точку) и ваш собственный код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На то чтобы установить соединение браузера с web-socket-server ом у меня ушла неделя по 8 часов в день, потому что с этим ни разу не сталкивался. И в помощь таким же как я приведу те открытия которые не новичкам очевидны, а впервые столкнувшимся в помощь и понимание.

1 Не надо заморачиваться с портами сервера, особенно с фаэрволами. Достаточно socket-server у указать какой порт вы хотите открыть на loopback, он же localhos, он же 127.0.0.1.

**Важно** : *порты с 1 по 1024 зарезервированы ОС - их лучше не трогать. В вашем распоряжении соответственно с 1025 по 65500 порты*

2 Настройки Nginx должны быть минимальными

```
#обязательно пробел между словом и скобкой
server {
   # череда настроек вашего сервера
   # ---------------------------
   # вписываем настройки для работы с сокет-сервером с поддержкой web-sockets
   # вы можете написать вместо /ws/ все что пожелаете, лишь бы обратиться
   # по java-script у
   location /ws/ {
      # соединяем порт, открытый по localhos(доступный только внутри) 
      # с внешним миром (я использовал в данном примере порт 1100)
      # если у вас вырублен сокет сервер и процесс на порту не висит
      # то никто не подключится к этому порту
      proxy_pass http://localhost:1100;
      # если вы хотите чтобы соединение не разрывалось - выставите время 
      # в секундах - у меня 10 часовой рабочий день 60*60*10
      proxy_read_timeout 36000;
   }
   # -------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

по сути всего 3 основные строчки

```
location /ws/ {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:1100;
}
```

**Важные правила :**

после сохранения конфига,
чтобы убедиться что вы не накосячили в синтаксисе конфига nginx - выполните команду в консоли

```
sudo nginx -t
```

если пишет ok то перезапуск nginx

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```

Собственно этого достаточно чтобы принимать входящие сигналы из интернета

Если у вас ошибка 500 в браузере в консоли, то вы не на тот адрес в интернете стучитесь.
Смею заметить, если у вас в браузере пишет ошибку  502, 301, 302, 200, то это некорректный код в сокет-сервере, он же web-socket-server.
В данном случае начните с малого - отправьте браузеру заголовок и проверьте кодировку - только UTF-8 можно и без BOM

```
//$command = 'HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols' . PHP_EOL;
//это неправильная команда - потому что для HTTP обязателен символ 
//переноса карретки
//$command = 'HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\n\r';
//это тоже неправильно! из за этого я убил пару дней, а все почему?
// \n\r в одинарных ковычках читаются как текст!!!, а нужно как спецсимволы
//вот теперь правильно и у вас все получиться
$command = "HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols\n\r";
socket_write( $client, $command);
```

если после этого браузер будет ругаться на что то другое, то вы на правильном пути и уже отправили браузеру 101 код ответа! Рекомендую также смотреть какие заголовки ваш сокет сервер отправляет.
Пишите сюда свои наблюдения...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
это из браузера Google-Chrome из раздела Network (чтобы включить - нажми F12 и перейди по вкладке Network и обнови страницу)

Бывает так, что вы некорректно закрыли порт, т.е. вы хотите вновь запустить сокет сервер, а консоль вам пишет - этот порт уже используется.
Для того чтобы посмотреть какой процесс использует этот порт запустите команду

```
lsof -i tcp:1100
```

в моем случае я прослушиваю 1100 порт
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и чтобы освободить порт вбиваем команду

```
sudo kill -9 13905
```

В моем случае 13905 - PID серверного процесса, висящего на процессоре сервера и использующий порт, в моем случае это порт 1100
параметр -9 означает что мы отсылаем команду на процессор *убить процесс*

Для простоты завершения работы сервера я использую сокет-клиент с командой выключения сокет сервера.

Для того чтобы полностью установить соединение с браузером по web-socket у вам необходимо отправить на запрос от браузера http заголовок с исчерпывающей для браузера информацией
а именно

```
$command = 'HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols' . PHP_EOL
 .'Upgrade: websocket' . PHP_EOL
 .'Connection: Upgrade' . PHP_EOL
 .'Sec-WebSocket-Accept: '.$responce_key . PHP_EOL
 .'Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13' . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
socket_write( $client, $command);
```

Как сформировать зашифрованный `$responce_key` ?

**Ответ :**
*Для этого вам надо взять из заголовка "Sec-WebSocket-Key: \n\r" http запроса - ключ, который вам посылает web-socket и обработать его функцией*

```
function getWebSocketAccept( $key )
{
    $guid = '258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11';
    $sec_websocket_accept = $key . $guid;
    $sec_websocket_accept = sha1($sec_websocket_accept, true);
    return base64_encode($sec_websocket_accept);
}
```

И тогда наверняка, вдруг запляшут "облака" :)

Что бы web-socket-server смог вообще что либо понять, какую информацию ему отсылает браузер, после успешного "рукопожатия" веб-сокет-серверу необходимо будет раскодировать сообщение, а чтобы браузер понимал что прислал ему web-socket-server, данные должны поступать в закодированном виде.
Функции(требуют проверки)

```
/**
     * Декодирование строки
     * 
     * @param string $str
     * @param boolean $message_only
     * @return array | string
     */
    function decode($str, $message_only = false)
    {
        /* Разбираем заголовок */
        $header = unpack("n", $str)[1];         /* Рапаковываем первые 16 бит, порядок байт «big endian», т.к. сетевой протокол */
        $data = [];
        $data['fin']            = (bool) (($header >> (16 - 1))  & 0b1);        /* Финальный фрейм. Если сообщение нефрагмантированное, то всегда 1, если фрагмантированно, то у последнего 1 у остальных 0 */
        $data['rsv1']           = (bool) (($header >> (16 - 2))  & 0b1);        /* Флаги RSV1, RSV2, RSV3 служат для расширений протокола, почти всегда в false */
        $data['rsv2']           = (bool) (($header >> (16 - 3))  & 0b1);
        $data['rsv3']           = (bool) (($header >> (16 - 4))  & 0b1);
        $data['opcode']         = (int)  (($header >> (16 - 8))  & 0b1111);     /* Тип фрейма */
        $data['is_mask']        = (bool) (($header >> (16 - 9))  & 0b1);        /* Замаскированы ли фреймы */
        $data['length_prev']    = (int)  (($header >> (16 - 16)) & 0b1111111);  /* Предварительная длина фрейма */

        /* Определяем тип фрейма */
        $data['type'] = $this->_get_type_frame($data['opcode']);

        /* Определяем длину фрейма */
        if ($data['length_prev'] < 126)
        {
            $data['length'] = $data['length_prev'];
        }
        elseif ($data['length_prev'] === 126)
        {
            $data['length'] = unpack("x2/n", $str)[1];
        }
        elseif ($data['length_prev'] > 126)
        {
//          $data['length'] = unpack("x2/J", $str)[1];
            $data['length'] = unpack("x2/x4/N", $str)[1];
        }

        /* Маска */
        if ($data['is_mask'])
        {
            if ($data['length_prev'] < 126)
            {
                $mask = substr($str, 2, 4);
            }
            elseif ($data['length_prev'] === 126)
            {
                $mask = substr($str, 2 + 2, 4);
            }
            elseif ($data['length_prev'] > 126)
            {
                $mask = substr($str, 2 + 8, 4);
            }
        }

        /* Тело запроса */
        $message_start = 2;
        if ($data['length_prev'] < 126)
        {

        }
        elseif ($data['length_prev'] === 126)
        {
            $message_start += 2;
        }
        elseif ($data['length_prev'] > 126)
        {
            $message_start += 8;
        }

        if ($data['is_mask'])
        {
            $message_start += 4;
        }
        $data['message_start'] = $message_start;

        $message = substr($str, $message_start, $data['length']);

        /* Размаскируем сообщение */
        if ($data['is_mask'])
        {
            $length = strlen($message);

            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) 
            {
                $message[$i] = $message[$i] ^ $mask[$i % 4];
            }
        }

        $data['message'] = $message;

        /* Возвращаем сообщение */
        if ($message_only === false)
        {
            return $data;
        }
        else
        {
            return $data['message'];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Закодировать строку
     * 
     * @param string $str
     * @param boolean $is_mask
     * @return string
     */
    function encode($str, $is_mask = false)
    {
        $bin = "";

        /* Основные флаги */
        $data = 
        [
            "fin" => 0b1,
            "rsv1" => 0b0,
            "rsv2" => 0b0,
            "rsv3" => 0b0,
            "opcode" => 0x1,
            "is_mask" => $is_mask === true ? 0b1 : 0b0,
            "length" => strlen($str)
        ];

        /* Предварительная длина */
        if ($data['length'] < 126)
        {
            $data['length_prev'] = $data['length'];
        }
        elseif ($data['length'] < 65536)
        {
            $data['length_prev'] = 126;
        }
        else
        {
            $data['length_prev'] = 127;
        }

        /* Заголовок */
        $header = $data['fin'];
        $header = $header << 1 | $data['rsv1'];
        $header = $header << 1 | $data['rsv2'];
        $header = $header << 1 | $data['rsv3'];
        $header = $header << 4 | $data['opcode'];
        $header = $header << 1 | $data['is_mask'];
        $header = $header << 7 | $data['length_prev'];
        $bin .= pack("n", $header);

        /* Расширенная длина тела */
        if ($data['length_prev'] === 126)
        {
            $bin .= pack("n", $data['length']);
        }
        elseif ($data['length_prev'] > 126)
        {
            $bin .= pack("x4N", $data['length']);
        }

        /* Маскировать сообщение */
        if ($is_mask)
        {
            $mask = substr(md5(microtime()), 0, 4);
            $bin .= $mask;

            $length = strlen($str);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) 
            {
                $str[$i] = $str[$i] ^ $mask[$i % 4];
            }
        }

        $bin .= $str;

        return $bin;
    }
```

Comment: Помогая другим - ты помогаешь себе!

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте например socket.io для nodejs(https://socket.io/) или ratchet для php(http://socketo.me/)
На мой взгляд вы в дебрях `epoll c++`.
С помощью представленных мной инструментов можно с легкостью за 1-30мин установить соединение 101 браузера с сервером

> причем когда вырубаю сокет сервер, вебсокет, ждущий ответа - тут же реагирует что соединение разорвано

- так и должно быть.
Сокет можно представить себе как вилку воткнутую в розетку.
Исключая из цепи вилку или розетку вы нарушите цепь.

В программировании сокетов аналогично, если уронить серверную часть, то получите ошибку соединения на клиентской стороне(т.е. клиентская часть будет искать узел)
Если уроните клиентскую, то сервер принимает событие дисконекта от клиента(на это событие можно отключать клиентов)