# Как настроить WebSocket для PhP языка?

Tags: php, websocket

Помогите разобраться с серверной частью WebSocket - а, что нужно об этом знать, как настроить серверную часть, какие приложения или библиотеки использовать,
есть ли особенности при использовании WebSocket - а  с PHP и Laravel ?

Если есть ссылки или предложения, по этим вопросом буду рад их принять ?

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/broadcasting

Comment: https://packagist.org/packages/cboden/ratchet

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/706832/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-websocket